# Combine masonry layout with isotope filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masonry, jquery-isotope

Starting to pull my hair out with this one. I have a masonry script that sets a layout and a filter that works, but doesn't call the layout. I need to somehow integrate the two so that the layout still works.

I have this filter:

```
<ul id="filters">
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All sizes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".red">Wide</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".blue">High</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".green">Small</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function() {

    var $container = $('#k2Container');     

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.itemContainer',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '#blank-item',
                        itemSelector: '.itemContainer',
                        gutter: 10,
                        isResizeBound: false,
                        isOriginLeft: true,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false
                        }
        }
    });

    $('#filters').on('click', 'a', function() {
        var selector = $(this).data('filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            resizable: false,
        });

     $("k2Container").isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
</script>
```

And these masonry settings:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*
     * For K2 Masonry 
     */ 
        /*
         * Defined element Masonry
         */
        var loader          = $('.loading_spinner_wrapper'),
            viewmore        = $('.view-more'),
            itemContainer   = $('.itemContainer'),
            k2Container     = $('#k2Container'),
            masonry         = $('.jux-k2-masonry'),
            blank = $('<div id="blank-item" class="itemContainer"></div>')
                        .css({
                            height: 0,
                            visibility : 'hidden'
                        }).appendTo(masonry);


            //Show loading content
            //loader.css('display','block');
            // Hide view more content
            //viewmore.css('display','none');
            // Caroulse
            itemContainer.each(function(){
                if($(this).find('.jux-gallery').length !== 0){
                    $(this).addClass('gallery');
                }
            });

            $('#itemListLeading').find('.gallery').addClass('important-width');

            $('.jux-gallery').carousel();           

            masonry.show();
            // MODIFY JS 
            //--------------------------------
            if(!masonry.length){
                return false;
            }

            //var newBaseWidth = updateItem(masonry, 0);
            /*
            * Call JS Masonry
            */
            var lastWndWidth = 0,
                lastWndHeigh = 0,
                itemWidth    = 0,
                gridWidth    = 0,
                usid = null,
                updateMasonry = function(){
                    masonry.masonry('layout');
                },
                updateContainer= function(){
                    lastWndWidth = $(window).width();

                    var baseWidth = blank.css('width', '').width(), // base width
                        contWidth = masonry.width(), // container width
                        cols = Math.round(contWidth / baseWidth), //  detect number of columns by it's container
                        newBaseWidth = Math.floor((contWidth - (cols - 1) * 10 ) / cols); // update new width
                    blank.width(itemWidth);
                    var grid = $('#itemListLeading .gallery').css('width','').width();
                        gridWidth = (Math.floor(grid / newBaseWidth) * newBaseWidth) 
                                    + (Math.floor(grid / newBaseWidth) - 1) * 10;
                    $('#itemListLeading .gallery').width(gridWidth);                
                    if (itemWidth != newBaseWidth) {
                        itemWidth = newBaseWidth;
                        gridWidth = gridWidth;
                        updateItems();
                    }
                    // Update masonry Height
                    lastWndHeigh = masonry.height();
                    //layout
                    updateMasonry();
                },
                updateItems = function(items){
                    if(itemWidth == 0){
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(!items){
                        items = $(masonry.masonry('getItemElements'));
                    }
                    items.width(itemWidth);
                    $('#itemListLeading .gallery').width(gridWidth);
                },
                initMasonry= function(){
                    masonry.masonry({
                        columnWidth: '#blank-item',
                        itemSelector: '.itemContainer',
                        gutter: 10,
                        isResizeBound: false,
                        isOriginLeft: true,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false
                        }
                    });
                    //bind smartresize and start
                    $(window).bind('resize.masonry orientationchange.masonry', function(e){
                        clearTimeout(usid);
                        if(lastWndWidth != $(window).width() || e.isTrigger){
                            usid = setTimeout(updateContainer,200);
                        }
                    }).trigger('resize.masonry');
                };
            //load images
            masonry.imagesLoaded().always( function( instance ) {
                initMasonry();
            });

            // END MODIFY JS
            //--------------------------------

    })
```

Comment: Can you put this on the fiddle...

Comment: Are you trying to use isotope.js and masonry.js together? You're calling isotope.js with the masonry layout under your filter code but it looks like masonry.js in your masonry code.

Comment: I attempted to. I'm not sure how else to call the masonry.js with normal jQuery filters.